# Value set from JS controller does not reflect on CMP file

Tags: controller, aura, javascript-controller, javascript-debugging

I am working on a functionality that hides a button and uses a wrapper for assigning  a value (ex. wrapperClass.showButton = false). I checked the Apex debug and it is setting the wrapperClass.showButton to false. I also checked on the JS controller and it gets the value being returned from Apex which is "false". I have a condition on CMP that shows the button if attribute !v.wrapperClass.showButton is true. Even the value being set on JS is false, the button still shows. I checked for spelling errors too but there is none.

```
 //For the reference, here is the JS:

({
    

doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        debugger
        let request = {
            objId: component.get("v.recordId")
        }        
          
       customUtils.callServerAction(component, "c.showButton", request).then((res)=>{
            
          
            component.set("v.wrapperClass", res.getReturnValue());

            console.log('showButton::' +  wrapperClass.showButton:'); //value is false

    
            
        })
      
    }
})
```

Comment: ` console.log('showButton::' +  wrapperClass.showButton:');` has two problems: (1) extra `'` at the end would be a syntax error, preventing deployment, and (2) `wrapperClass` isn't shown anywhere else in the code. As such, we don't really know what's wrong with your code. We'd need more information to properly help you.